# UIAlertController Slow to Appear and Dismiss - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, performance, uialertcontroller

I am developing an iOS app, using Swift, and am having two issues with the UIAlertController being quite slow!

**1 - Slow and jittery to appear**

I have set up a UITableViewController, and when I tap a cell, it fires the following code:

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Enter Exam Grade", message: nil, preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

        alertController.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler({(textField: UITextField) in
            textField.placeholder = "Earned"
            textField.keyboardType = .NumberPad
        })

        alertController.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler({(textField: UITextField) in
            textField.placeholder = "Out of"
            textField.keyboardType = .NumberPad
        })

        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: {
            (alert: UIAlertAction) in

            if let gradeTextField = alertController.textFields!.first as UITextField? {

                if let outOfTextField = alertController.textFields!.last as UITextField? {

                    if (gradeTextField.text != "" && outOfTextField.text != "") {

                        print(gradeTextField.text)
                        print(outOfTextField.text)

                    }

                }

            }

        }))

        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: nil))

        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

When I navigate to the view, and tap the cell for the first time, I get a jittery and slow load of the alert, as you can see in the GIF below. Interestingly, subsequent taps load generally smoothly and quickly.

[image: Jittery to appear]

EDIT: The GIF has a framerate a little too slow, so I have attached some stills taken from a slowed down video of it:

a) First tap of "Grade Exam", the alert begins to appear in centre of the screen, but then shifts up (in a jolt) to the correct position).

[image]
[image]

b) Subsequent taps, the alert appears in the correct upper position from the beginning.

[image]
[image]

**2 - Keyboard slow to dismiss when Alert dismisses**

I have seen this issue all around StackOverflow, with no real satisfactory solutions. When you tap the Cancel button, the Alert will dismiss quickly, but then the keyboard takes a long time to dismiss also. This should be instantaneous, as the hanging keyboard leaves a bad impression with users.

[image: Slow to dismiss keyboard]

Comment: did you tried 'cmd' + 'T'. it toggles the slow animation

Comment: @Ccr so I just checked it in the simulator, and the bug appears to only happen when I am running the app on my physical device, but not the simulator...

Comment: What're you running it on? Might be a performance issue.

Comment: I think animation disappear is a bug since iOS9.

Comment: @user2277872 i'm running it on an iPhone 5 :) surely this device doesn't have a performance issue just on displaying an alert!?

Comment: No you're right. I was thinking if it were an iPhone 4s, it might be a possibility though haha

Answer (score 0):

The launching of your keyboard seems to be "normal" from the gif files you have provided. However assuming if it is slow, maybe you could try this if it does load faster.

Just to mention I've not tried this code and typing off from here.

For slow display of keyboard.

```
textField.placeholder = "Out of"
textField.keyboardType = .NumberPad
textField.becomeFirstResponder()
```

For slow hiding of keyboard.

```
alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: {
            (alert: UIAlertAction) in
       self.view.endEditing(true)
}))
```

Comment: i did the same thing still having issue